# concating renaming duplicate rows in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like following

```
ID   student_name        dept        email

1    Mary Wise           Eng         mary-wise@xxx.cc
2    John Walter         Sc          john-walter@xxx.cc
3    Sophia Jacob        Politics    sophia-jacob@xxx.cc
4    Ava William         Eng         ava-william@xxx.cc
5    Mary Wise           Politics    mary-wise@xxx.cc
6    John Walter         Eng         john-walter@xxx.cc
7    John Walter         Politics    john-walter@xxx.cc
8    Sophia              Eng         sophia@xxx.cc
9    Emma                Eng         emma@xxx.cc
10   Sherlock            Eng         sherlock@xxx.cc
```

The email ids col is generated by firstname-lastname@xxx.cc
The problem is when the name is same the email id is also same. 
I want the email id to be appended with 1, 2, 3 when same name exists.

```
For example in table above 
the mary-wise on 5th row should be mary-wise1@xxx.cc, 
6th row should be, john-walter1@xxx.cc, 
7th row should be, john-walter2@xxx.cc
```

How can I update my email column with mysql query as fast as possible. 
I tried with php with mysql it takes too long when the table contains million rows.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL will enumerate the duplicates:

```
select t.*,
       @rn := if(@StudentName = StudentName, 1, @rn + 1) as seqnum,
       @StudentName := StudentName
from table t cross join
     (select @rn := 0, @StudentName := '') const
order by StudentName;
```

You can put this in an `update` using `join`:

```
update t join
       (select t.*,
           @rn := if(@StudentName = StudentName, 1, @rn + 1) as seqnum,
           @StudentName := StudentName
        from table t cross join
             (select @rn := 0, @StudentName := '') const
        order by StudentName
       ) toupdate
       on t.name = toupdate.name and toupdate.seqnum > 1
    set email = concat(replace(t.StudentName, ' ', '-'), toupdate.seqnum - 1, '@xxx.cc);
```

Comment: email is the column name in which i want to update the values where it has more than 1 same entry. The consecutive entries should add 1,2,3 etc

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's better for you to make `email` column unique and to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax (more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)).

You still need to keep track of a number you want to append to the new value. For this purpose you can create a separate table with auto increment field and just get the new value from there.

Comment: I cannot make it unique because the values you see in my question are available to me. Now my job is to make it unique by adding 1,2,3 etc as per the occurence number of that email.

Comment: You can create a temporary table with unique `email` field and original ID, insert records one by one from the main table using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and then, using original ID field, update the main table with the new values.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy to achieve if you had CTE (maybe switch to postgres 9 if you can):

```
SELECT
 id
 , student_name
 , concat(
   replace(lower(student_name), ' ', '-')
   , case 
     when cnt > 1 then numb
   end
   ,'@xxx.cc'
 ) as newmail
FROM (
 SELECT
 count(*) over (partition BY student_name) as cnt
 , count(*) over (partition BY student_name order by id)  as numb 
 , id
 , student_name
 FROM tab1
 order by id
 ) subq
```

[sqlFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bb71d/15/1)